# Select statement using index

Tags: sqlite

I want to access a column using index name using this statement:
String select=" SELECT  * FROM table_name WITH INDEX("+key+") ";

Error:
11-05 08:18:55.443: E/AndroidRuntime(5525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.index/com.example.index.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INDEX": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM table_name WITH INDEX(onlineShopping)

Comment: You might need to replace `WITH INDEX (...)` by `INDEXED BY ...`. See [SQLite SQL documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_indexedby.html).

Comment: @halfbit tried this but  it still gives an error

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping that error a secret.

Comment: @CL. Statement :"SELECT  *  FROM  "+TABLE_NAME+"  INDEXED BY "+INDEX_NAME+"  ";    E.G.  (INDEX_NAME = "GAMES")                                                                                                                                                          ERROR= android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near cannot use index :GAMES: while compiling: SELECT * FROM TABLE  INDEXED BY GAMES

Comment: Edit your question. And please explain what you mean with "using index".